# Responsive height element for JWPlayer using LESS and JADE

Tags: node.js, less, pug, jwplayer

I am new to Jade and Less and am trying to build a responsive video player that is horizontally centered and resizes based on the height of its div.

Specifically, the player element is within the .banner which has been set to 40% of the screen height. I am attempting to maximize the player to the be as large as possible while maintaining a 16X9 aspect ratio. My approach attempts to calculate the width as a % given the banner height and 16X9 aspect ratio.

The JW Player setup API allows the **width** to be set by px or % while the **height** can only be set by px. http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413113-configuration-options-reference#basic.

Two questions:

1. How can I calculate the height and width of the .banner? I have
   made quite a few attempts but I keep throwing errors as I can't get
   the syntax right.
2. The approach I am taking seems terribly inefficient. Is there a more appropriate method?

**Jade file:**

```
block body
    div.row
      div.banner
        div.imaginary
        div.text-center
          #jwplayer
            script(type='text/javascript').
              var givenheight = 460
              var givenwidth = 2560
              var setwidth2 = { percentage: givenheight/9*16/givenwidth*100 + "%"}

              jwplayer('jwplayer').setup({
                file: 'XXX',
                image: 'XXX',
                width: setwidth2.percentage,
                //height: '300', //height can only be set as px (not %)
                aspectratio: '16:9',
                autostart: 'true'
              });
```

**LESS file:**

```
.banner {
  background: #ff0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 40%; 
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;

  .text-center {
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 50%;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, I believe:

```
width: '100%',
aspectratio: '16:9',
```

Setting width like that, with the aspectratio variable, should fill the display.

You can also try to add:

```
height: '100%',
```

But it may not be needed, as the width and aspectratio should be all you need.

Comment: height defined as a % is not listed in the JW Player support documentation however it seems to be working.